# Force an error or give a warning in one of the if conditions in C

Tags: c

I want to write a function in C and to put a condition in it. If the condition isn't  met the program gives and error and prevents the user (developer) from compiling the code.

For example:

```
void func(int x)
    {
        if (x > 0)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //give an error and stops the code from compiling
        }
    }
```

Comment: That can't be done at compile time as the compiler doesn't know which branch of code will run until it, er, runs. Perhaps you want [`assert`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) which will stop the program if it is hit but that is run time not compile time.

Comment: In that case you need to find a way to figure out the value of `x` before runtime, and this is impossible.

Comment: Your program has to be compiled before it can even be run.  That precludes a compile-time error for a runtime condition.  Just print an error message to `stderr` and exit with non-zero status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> prevents the user (developer) from compiling the code.

There's a problem there. You can decide on the user's behaviour, but you can't decide on the compilation of the program. If the code is right (right in the language sense, so it makes sense to the compiler), it will compile, else it won't. You can't make up new arbitrary rules for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can even run a program written in C, the compilation needs to be fulfilled.

Functions are called at run-time and so are the parameter values determined at run-time, too.

You can't make the compilation of your code dependent upon the variable `x` in C.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is basically completely impossible.

Let's take an example. Assume that you want to manufacture an elevator, and you set the weight limit to 800 kilograms. You could build in something that makes the elevator stop if the weight exceeds the limit.

So take the scenario where we program the elevator so that it does not move if the weight limit is exceeded. That would typically be done with an `assert()` or something like that.

You could also in various way try to prevent this from happening, like making the elevator very small so that you cannot fit too many people. But that is not a fail safe option. We have restricted the volume, but nothing prevents a person from bringing a big chunk of solid gold into the elevator.

The point here is that you can measure the weight before moving the elevator, since this is done at runtime. But preventing someone from even trying to exceed the limit is virtually impossible.

In the general case, what you're asking for is completely impossible. What you can do is something like this:

```
void func(int x)
{
    assert(x>0);

    /* Do stuff */
}
```

And a slightly related thing that is possible is to create a test that is a part of the build process. You cannot prevent compilation the way you want, but you can use it to fail the whole build process. An example.

```
// main.c

int add(int x, int y) 
{
    return x+y;
}

bool test()
{
    if(add(4,5) != 9) return false;
    return true;
}
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "--test") == 0) {
        if(!test()) {
            printf("Test failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // More tests

        printf("All tests passed\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    /* Rest of the main function */
}
```

Then you create a Makefile that compiles `main.c` and then calls `./a.out --test` as a part of the build process. The above example is a very simple case, and for a more realistic case I would have made it a bit more sophisticated, but it shows how it can be done. Also, there are libraries that can take care of this kind of stuff, but this is a way to do it without having to use that.